# Customer Portal gets 404 error trying to display logo. Bug?

Tags: javascript, customer-portal, bug

I am just re-factoring a **Customer Portal** (*not Communities*) on an old org and I come across the following error - just wondering if anyone has seen something like this before. Please have a look at the screenshots below:

[image]

If I debug more, it looks like a Salesforce.com script is trying to load a resource that does not exist. This script does not sound familiar at all to me, have a look at he screenshot:

[image: Salesforce.com script]

**If this is a bug, how do I report it? Does Salesforce.com still support Customer Portal since the product SKU moved to Communities. Looking forward to thoughts and feedback!**

Comment: where is the screenshot?????

Comment: Both are in the posts.

Comment: This happens on every Salesforce page I go to, regardless of user license or type.

Answer (score 6):

The image file `logo180.png` is obviously deleted or moved (or was never there).

I found that this error also shows in our org as well if you you open developer tools and refresh the page. I did a little digging and it appears the file is related to some marketing survey Salesforce created.

Here's the line in my org:

```
<script>var SFDCMktUrl='https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png';</script>
```

Later on in the page, the variable `SFDCMktUrl` is referenced in this script:

```
<script async="" defer="" src="/jslibrary/1421275782000/sfdc/MarketingSurveyResponse.js"></script>
```

This is clearly a Salesforce bug/defect.

Comment: The logo180.png is a Salesforce resource which I don't have access to. The script is a salesforce script as you can see attributes like SFDCMktUrl.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this discussion on Salesforce Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D6qzAAC), this is actually working as designed. It's somehow part of a malware detection scheme. Perhaps if logo180.png that's a sign an account has been hacked and Salesforce will freeze their account. So, bizarrely, in this case missing 17181/logo180.png is a good thing.

Newer versions of Chrome (like v.47, currently only in Chrome Canary) have the option to block requests for certain URLs in the network window. This option is persistent, so you can just put logo180.png in there one time and it will never bug you about it again.

[image: Accessing the Request Blocking option]
[image: Adding the file to block (regex)]
[image: logo180.png blocked in the network panel and no longer showing in the console]

Answer (score 0):

I had same bug in using base SF layout ... this script requirement generates 404 response