# OnClick JavaScript and Commandbutton

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a Visualforce page with a custom button that calls JavaScript to execute a script. When I click the button, I get a ***404 Error (Not Found)*** error.  Apparently, this is due to an SFDC resource called "logo180.png".  It seems this is a known issue that occurs by design to prevent malware.  However, it prevents by button from working on my VF page.  Does anyone know how I can avoid this?

```
<apex:page standardController="Engage_Short_Form__c">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendViaDocuSign() {
        var CRL = ''; 
        var DST = ''; 
        var CES = '';
        CRL = 'Email~{!JSENCODE(Engage_Short_Form__c.Partner_Email__c)};FirstName~{!JSENCODE(Engage_Short_Form__c.Partner_Contact_First_Name__c)};LastName~{!JSENCODE(Engage_Short_Form__c.Partner_Contact_Last_Name__c)};Role~Signer1,Email~jneilan@outbrain.com;FirstName~John;LastName~Neilan;Role~Signer 2'; 
        DST = '0E9AB63C-62C0-4D01-B91A-E58849B7B573'; 
        CES = 'Insertion Order signature request for {!JSENCODE(Engage_Short_Form__c.Partner_Legal_Name__c)}';
        window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&STB=1&SourceID={!Engage_Short_Form__c.Id}&LA=0&CRL="+CRL+"&DST="+DST+"&CES="+CES; 
    }
</script>



   <apex:form >

            <center><button class="btn" onclick="sendViaDocuSign()">Send via DocuSign</button></center>
```

Comment: Looks like there is a quotation mark issue in the line of code where you are setting `window.location.href`

Comment: Thanks, missed that, but I'm still getting the same resource error.

Comment: What makes you think that logo180.png is causing a problem with your `window.location.href` call? Is it just appearing as a failed request in the developer tools, or is it directly related to the location change? By Known Issue I assume you are referring to [Salesforce can not find /17181/logo180.png](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D6qzAAC)

Comment: are you directy able to access "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope" from same page where you are clicking button ?

Comment: See also [Customer Portal gets 404 error trying to display logo. Bug?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/85742/102)

Comment: @Daniel - the 404 (Not Found) error specifically references the logo190.png resource in the console.  And yes, that is the issue I was referencing.

Comment: @Jitendra - Yes, if I hardcode the URL, I am able to access it.  Also, if I put it as a hardcoded outputLink, it also works.  There's just something with the JavaScript that is not liked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone.  I figured out if I added ***return false;*** to my onClick, the button works!  Thanks for all your help!

```
<button class="btn" onclick="sendViaDocuSign();return false;">Send via DocuSign</button>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you change the title of your post as the issue is more related to the onclick javascript code than the 404 which is a red herring.